# How to switch two layout components dynamically

Tags: android

I have a customized layout as shown in the picture.[image: picture]
Activation is done by SMS. So once SMS activation comes, "Not activated yet text" disappears and green arrow is switched with a gray arrow. My layout xml file is shown below. I have two image views `"@+id/list_arrow"` and `"@+id/green_list_arrow"`.
In `SMSReceiver`, I update with

```
lvObjects = (ListView)myView.findViewById(android.R.id.list);       
lvObjects.post(new Runnable() { public void run() { MyListFragment.adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); } } );
```

In the customized ListView's `getView()`, I updated as if "activated" I use `@+id/list_arrow` and "not activated" I use `@+id/green_list_arrow`. When it is tested, "Not activated text" is disappeared, but green arrow is never updated. What could be missing?
Thanks

Edit1: Once activated, I also want to stop the `setOnClickListener()`. How can I do that?

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) { 
        BitmapWorkerTask task = null;
        View vi=convertView;
        ViewHolder viewHolder=new ViewHolder();
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) this.getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        if(vi==null){

            vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row, parent, false);
            viewHolder.id=(TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.title);
            viewHolder.thumbnailImage=(ImageView)vi.findViewById(R.id.list_image);
            viewHolder.activationStatus = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.activated);
            if(position > maxRowNumber)
                  maxRowNumber = position;

            vi.setTag(viewHolder);            
        }else{
            viewHolder=(ViewHolder)vi.getTag();               
        }
        viewHolder.thumbnailImage.setOnClickListener(new onMyClick(position)); 
        viewHolder.id.setText(listIDs.get(position));

         if(activationState.get(position).equals("Activated")) {             
             viewHolder.arrow=(ImageView)vi.findViewById(R.id.list_arrow);
             viewHolder.activationStatus.setText(""); 

         }
         else{
            viewHolder.arrow=(ImageView)vi.findViewById(R.id.green_list_arrow);
            viewHolder.activationStatus.setText(activationState.get(position));
                viewHolder.activationStatus.setTextColor(android.graphics.Color.GRAY);
                viewHolder.arrow.setOnClickListener(new onMyArrowClick(position));
         }


         String hasnoimageyet = "no";
         if(position > maxRowNumber && maxRowNumber > 3 ){//it is for sure

             hasnoimageyet = this.listRowhasnoImageyet.get(position); 
         }

             String id = listIDs.get(position);
             task.execute(id);   

         }      
        return vi;
    }

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/list_background_selector"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="5dip" >

    <!--  ListRow Left sied Thumbnail image -->
    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/thumbnail"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="3dip"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:background="@drawable/image_bg"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dip">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/list_image"
            android:layout_width="50dip" 
            android:focusable="false"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:onClick="imageViewisClicked"    
            android:contentDescription="@string/image_view_description"
            android:layout_height="50dip"
            android:src="@drawable/icons_preview"
            />

    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/thumbnail"
        android:textColor="#040404"
        android:typeface="sans"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"/>

     <!-- Rightend Arrow -->
     <ImageView 
        android:id="@+id/list_arrow"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:contentDescription="@string/arrow"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:src="@drawable/arrow"

        android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>

      <ImageView 
        android:id="@+id/green_list_arrow"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:contentDescription="@string/arrow"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:src="@drawable/green_arrow"

        android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>

     <TextView
        android:id="@+id/activated"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/title"
        android:paddingLeft="20dp"
        android:typeface="sans"
        android:textStyle="italic"
        android:textSize="15sp"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I update as follow. But it is not switching two imageviews. Just editing the imageview components. if(activationState.get(position).equals("Activated")) {     
             //viewHolder.arrow=(ImageView)vi.findViewById(R.id.list_arrow);
    viewHolder.arrow.setImageResource(R.drawable.arrow);
             viewHolder.activationStatus.setText(""); 
             viewHolder.arrow.setEnabled(false);
             
         }. But I still want if i can switch the two ImageViews.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your layout you are drawing the green arrow over the grez one, no matter what. (because its below the other one in xml)

You could either toggle visibility of both according to state, or just have one ImageView for the arrows and change the bitmap. (code below)
The OnClickListener can be disabled by setting it to `null`.

```
if(activationState.get(position).equals("Activated")) {             
             viewHolder.arrow=(ImageView)vi.findViewById(R.id.list_arrow);
             viewHolder.arrow.setImageResource(R.drawable.arrow);
             viewHolder.activationStatus.setText(""); 
             viewHolder.thumbnailImage.setOnClickListener(null); 

} else{
            viewHolder.arrow=(ImageView)vi.findViewById(R.id.green_list);
            viewHolder.arrow.setImageResource(R.drawable.green_arrow);
            viewHolder.activationStatus.setText(activationState.get(position));
            viewHolder.activationStatus.setTextColor(android.graphics.Color.GRAY);
            viewHolder.arrow.setOnClickListener(new onMyArrowClick(position));
            viewHolder.thumbnailImage.setOnClickListener(new onMyClick(position)); 
}
```

An even smoother solution would be to use a [StateListDrawable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/StateListDrawable.html) or maybe even better a color filter on the image view.